# What is Turkey Bacon?

Tags: meat, bacon, turkey

Is there a standard part of the turkey that they use to process "turkey bacon"?  Is it pressed from different sections of the turkey?

Comment: Add "turkey" tag?

Comment: Excellent title question, considering it's not turkey, and it's not bacon.

Answer (score 11):

> The meat for turkey bacon comes from the thigh of the turkey and can be cured or uncured, smoked, chopped, and reformed into strips that resemble traditional pork bacon.

Source: [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkey_bacon)